# Springboot application start up fails and missing logs when using azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, kotlin

I am trying to migrate my springboot application written in kotlin to azure.
I added `spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets:4.5.0` dependency in my app, and added below configurations to `application.properties`.

```
my.secret=${my-azure-secret}
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-source-enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=<my-vault>.vault.azure.net/
```

After I add this, the spring boot initialization doesn't work any more and i can't find any logs.

```
log.info { "Log before springboot initialize" }
SpringApplication(MyApplication::class.java).run(*args)
log.info { "Log after springboot initialize" }
```

So, `Log before springboot initialize` is logged, and after that nothing happens (or I can't find any logs afterwards)

I already verified it is not related to any logback settings because if I remove the property `spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint` from `application.properties`, it boots up properly.

(I also tried to add the additional dependency `spring-cloud-azure-dependencies:4.5.0` )

Any clues/hints what is happening and how to resolve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you providing the application access to keyvault? Managed Identity?

Answer (score 1):

- Here I was able to boot the spring application using the same dependencies.
- But here I used the latest version of `spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets` i.e.  `5.0.0`  also my spring boot version is `3.0.2`

my dependencies:

```
<dependencies>  
 <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>  
 </dependency>  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure.spring/spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets -->  
  <dependency>  
 <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>  
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>  
 <version>5.0.0</version>  
 </dependency>  
  
 <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
 <scope>test</scope>  
 </dependency></dependencies>
```

- Also I use windows so instead of `my_azure_secret` instead of the `my-azure-secret`

output:
[image]